# How to update X++ map

Tags: dictionary, axapta, x++

I would like to change value for the key in map. How can I do it? 
Is it possible?

I have found only method insert(_key,_value) but I don't want to create new key with value, but change the value for the existing key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to edit the key**

Just remove the old key, then reinsert with the new key.

```
map = new Map(Types::String,Types::Real)
map.insert("a", 1);
map.insert("b", 2);
map.insert("c", 3);
map.remove("b");     // remove key
map.insert("y", 2);  // reinsert new key with value
```

**How to edit the value**

Just reinsert the value with [insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/map.insert.aspx). The key cannot have duplicates, instead it overwrites.

> Return Value
>   Type: boolean
>   true if the key did not already exist in the map and has been inserted; otherwise, false.
>   Remarks
>   If the key already exists in the map, the value is updated.

For example to manually sum line amount grouping on item group:

```
Map map = new Map(Types::String,Types::Real);
SalesLine sl;
while select sl where sl.SalesId == "123"
{
    map.insert(sl.ItemGroup, sl.LineAmount + (map.exists(sl.ItemGroup) ? map.lookup(sl.ItemGroup) : 0);
}
```

Is equivalent to but performance-wise inferior to:

```
select sum(LineAmount) sl group ItemGroup where sl.SalesId == "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove a key before you insert another value that is to update a key's value.  You simply call insert() again.

'insert()' would more accurately be called 'upsert()' in SQL terminology.

```
Map mymap;
mymap.insert('a',1.0);
mymap.insert('a',1.1);
info(strFmt('%1',mymap.lookup('a'))); // will return '1.1'
```